Minyan on Shabbat
Is the requirement to pray with a Minyan any different for Shabbat compared with the other days of the week?
What are the sources that support?

See Ramban Vayikra 23:2

It is a machlokes whether davening with a minyan is an obligation, but the Rabbis commenting on the topic do not indicate that Shabbos is any more important than other days: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Davening_with_a_Minyan#cite_note-2

on shabbos ….
one needs to go to shul
מדאורייתא to hear the leining
according to most psak
but during the week
all days are only d’rabanan

This is a big blunder. The requirement to hear Leining is only drabonon (see Rambam Hilchos Tefilah Chapter 12:1) Furthermore, there is a discussion in the poskim if the obligation is on the individual or perhaps only on the tzibbur.

most say it’s a d’oreissa.    Blunder??

Sourcing your answer would improve it significantly

@ user19400 See Aruch Hashulchan 135: 1, 2 in the name of Rif, Rambam, and Rosh that leining on Shabbos is only a takanah of Moshe. He also states that only parshas Zachor and perhaps Parah are dioraysa.
